# Timer issue presenting time

Tags: ios, swift, timer, dateformatter

I am trying to update the label with the current Time.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    let date = Date()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func updateTime(){

        label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .long)

    }


}
```

when I am using at `updateTime()` `label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .long)` I am getting the result that I want

When I am using `label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .long)`

the timer is not working. can someone please explain me ? ?

From my understanding I if I use a date and not Date() then I need a timer/counter to count and calculate. If so any suggestions ?

Thanks a lot

P

Comment: `date` is a constant value.  So even though `updateTime()` is called every second, it is setting the label to the same value every time.

Comment: @vacawama.Thanks a lot. And how I can represent the label showing counting from date and on every minute/second etc ?

Comment: Are you trying to make the label start at `0:00` and then count up each second?

Comment: No basically I want the label to start at date ( let date = Date() ) and start count up each second. By solving this small example I can solve my big one :)

Comment: What is wrong with using the `Date()` call like you are doing in your first example.  You said that works.  What about it is unacceptable to you?

Comment: No it is not unacceptable. It works and it is fine. It is just I am trying to get a constant var date (as Date) as you made it clear and make it start counting seconds up. So I can represent some label in a app that I am making with local times from a API that I am getting.

Comment: “... and make it start counting seconds up” ... Do you want to see the time, e.g. “3:55pm”, or the time elapsed (i.e. a stopwatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, `date` is a constant value. So even though updateTime() is called every second, it is setting the label to the same value every time.

From the comments, it seems you want to be able to advance a constant time when the timer is running.

To count up from an arbitrary `constant` `Date`, store a `start` time when the timer is started.  Use that to compute the `interval` the timer has been running, and then use that `interval` to advance `date`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    let date = Date()
    var start: Date?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Save the time when the timer starts 
        start = Date()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func updateTime(){

        // compute how long the timer has been running
        let interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(start!)

        // compute new date based on how long the timer has been running
        let newDate = date.addingTimeInterval(interval)
        label.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: newDate, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .long)

    }
}
```

The timer firing is not very accurate, and you might see your counting pause for a second and then jump 2 seconds.  If you make your timer interval something smaller, like `0.1` for instance, you can avoid a visual glitch.